# What's the difference in usage between に対して and にとって?

Tags: word-choice, usage

I often used に対して when speaking, and have noticed にとって as the favorite expression of the author who's book I'm now reading. What's the difference in usage? Are there any other similar  expressions I should be wary of misusing?

Answer (score 9):

These are *way* different expressions.  ～に対して can either mean "towards/to (someone・something)", or "as opposed to".  ～にとって means "for"/"thinking about it as" in a way that I can't better explain without just using examples:

### ～に対して:

> - 隣人に対して友情を表す　→　Be friendly ("show friendliness") to your neighbour
> - 男性に対して女性はドラマやロマンチックな映画が好き - As opposed to guys, girls like dramas, romantic movies, etc.

### ～にとって:

> - うちのワンちゃんにとって必ずしも猫が敵じゃない　→　To/for our dog, cats are not necessarily enemies
> - 教授にとって生徒が参加するほど講義が面白くなります　→　For a professor, giving a lecture is more interesting the more the students participate.

Comment: `にとって` means 'form the point of view of', 'from the perspective of'.

Comment: Since your second example has equal (balanced ) expressions `男性` and `女性`, you should avoid the sexually discriminative (non-balanced) expression pairs `guys` and `girls` in your English translation.

Comment: にとって is often translated to "for" in English however. Wouldn't 'from the point of view of' or 'from the perspective of' be along the lines of から見ると or から言うと?

Comment: @sawa: "Sexually discriminative" is a rather explosive way of describing what I think you're really trying to get at, which is that "guys and girls" is not the right translation for 「男性と女性」. I'm going to completely sidestep the sociopolitical quagmire of whether or not "guys and girls" is discriminatory (at best, that should be discussed on English SE, not here), but suggest that it's a loose but acceptable translation because that phrasing is common in English.

Comment: @Dave It is common in English, and that is why I feel I need to point this out to stop this. Furthermore, there is an equally discriminative word `野郎` in Japanese, which perfectly corresponds to the English 'guy'. If the Japanese was `野郎と女の子`, which is discriminative and is also commonly heard, then that will correspond to discriminative 'guys and girls'.

Comment: @phirru Yes, it can also be phrase as 'for', but English 'for' is ambiguous so I made used the expression 'from the point of view of'. They meand the same in the relevant sense. In fact, you can replace the Japanese examples by 'からすると'.

Comment: @Dave I can't follow your logic that "something is a loose acceptable translation because it is common". Doesn't that mean that 'りんご' can be translated as 'orange' because 'orange' is a commonly heard word?

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure I agree that "guys and girls" is discriminatory, or even impolite for that matter.  It sounds perfectly normal and unbiased in my opinion.  I don' know the word 野郎, but my dictionary says "rascal", and the word "guy" is not even close to the same nuance as "rascal".

Comment: Let's see what gets said: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34234/is-girls-a-suitable-complementary-term-to-go-along-with-guys

Comment: @Dave Looking forward for the results, but you may have missed my point. I am not saying that "girl" is discriminative. What I am saying is, why not use the word "boy", which sounds to be an equal male counterpart to "girl". If you replace "boy" with "guy", then why not do the same with "girl"? I suppose there isn't even a corresponding word for "girl". That is disciminative.

Comment: @Zach Although `野郎` may have the meaning `rascal`, it also has the meaning whose nuance is just as the same as `guy`, lacking the female counterpart, and connotating some kind of asymmetry between boys and girls. It is colloquial, so you can't necessarily expect to see in on the dictionary. There was an attempt to spread the artificially created female counterpart `女郎`, which was not widely appcepted.

Comment: @sawa - No American English speaker (that) I know would say "boys and girls" unless you are a school teacher talking to children who are like under 10 years old.  コメント、トピックからめっちゃ脱線しちゃって...

Comment: @sawa: Wow, yeah... I totally did not understand what you meant at first. Sorry about that. I see that you are simply saying that "boy" and "girl" are complementary the way that 「男性と女性」 are, and so it's the word "guy" that is out of place. The offered translation probably opted for "guy" so as to imply adults over children, but then that lands us in the problem of the limitation of English in that there isn't a great "guy" counterpart for females. Alright, I can concede this point to you. "Men and women" would be a more appropriate translation, and I would support editing the answer that way.

Comment: @Dave You got it right. That would be a perfect suggestion.